# Unable to delete or edit Google Cloud OAuth Client

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-cloud-console

We have recently set-up a number of OAuth clients within the Google Cloud console. We have noticed that a few hours after they are created we are no longer able to edit them. When we try and do see we see an error message saying there was an error when loading the client.

If we try and delete the clients we see a momentary spinner but the dialog doesn't close and the client isn't deleted.

Not being able to edit the client potentially makes sense, but not being able to delete it seems like it must be an error rather than a security feature.

What can cause this error? How can we delete the clients?

Comment: This could be a short term transient error or a problem with your system (firewall, antivirus, etc). The first item I check is to open a browser inspect window and see if there are any errors after repeating my steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem did turn out to be network related, if we tried the same operations on a machine on a different network then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth issues can root from several factors. First point that you need to validate is that you have all the access provision. I recommend checking the developer console for signs of error to have a starting point in the troubleshooting process.

Make sure as well that the network connection and security such as firewalls are configured correctly. Clearing the cache of the browser won’t hurt just to be sure that there are no stale plugins that could be affecting your OAuth. Attached is a support reference for OAuth that may come in handy. [1]

[1] https://support.google.com/cloud/topic/13841839?hl=en&ref_topic=3473162&sjid=262635825014489308-AP